# Slotted in, slotted into the starting grid

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> The cars were slotted in the starting grid.
>
> The cars were slotted into the starting grid.

Are they all valid and do they mean the same thing? What I was trying to say is that each car occupies a slot after placing on the grid during the qualifying rounds. I feel both roughly mean the same thing, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct object of **[slot in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slot-in)** is the thing that's slotted in.

> I can slot **you** in

If you want to specify where or when somebody or something is slotted in, you must use a preposition, for example **at** or **to**:

> I can slot you in **at** 3:30 pm
> I can slot you in **to** the afternoon session

If you omit the **to**, as in your first sentence:

> The cars were slotted **in** the starting grid.

**in** is taken as the preposition that links **the starting grid**, so the verb looks like **slotted** on its own rather than the phrasal verb **slotted in**, so it sounds like the cars have slots (holes) somewhere in their bodywork.

Comment: So slotted into?

Comment: @Sayaman yes: in this case, **in to** and **into** are equivalent.